# Updating a nested map in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a 2-level-nested map, how can I update each value on the 2nd level? Right now I'm doing this:

```
  items = Enum.map(items, fn(a) ->
    a.items2 = Enum.map(a.items2, fn(a2) ->
      Map.put(x2, :some_key, 123) 
    end)

    a
  end)
```

An error:

```
cannot invoke remote function "a.items2/0" inside match.
```

I basically know what this means, but how to fix it?

Note that `a.items2` might also has a nested map in itself.

Comment: Check out the `update_in` or `put_in` functions, they may be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map.put` outside as well:

```
items = Enum.map(items, fn(a) ->
  Map.put(a, :items2, Enum.map(a.items2, fn(a2) ->
    Map.put(x2, :some_key, 123) 
  end)
end)
```

or the map update syntax:

```
items = Enum.map(items, fn(a) ->
  %{a |
    items2: Enum.map(a.items2, fn(a2) ->
      Map.put(x2, :some_key, 123) 
    end)}
end)
```

Comment: There's `Map.update!`, the map update syntax (`%{a | items2: Enum.map(...)}`), `put_in`, `update_in`, probably more as well.

Comment: how does one do similar if you have a nested structrure where all nodes are Maps except leaf nodes which are MapSets rather than maps? Put_in doesn't seem to extend to MapSets?

Answer (score 2):

```
Enum.map(items, fn({k,v}) ->
  {k, put_in(v, [:items2, :some_key], 123)}    
end)
```