# Delete from a nested map in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I [know](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/02/01/elixir-best-practices-deeply-nested-maps) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716688/updating-a-nested-map-in-elixir) to put, get, and update nested maps in Elixir, using `put_in`, `get_in`, and `update_in`, but how do I "`delete_in`"?

Let's say I have this nested map, and I want to remove key `:c` and its associated value.

```
iex(1)> mymap = %{:a => %{:b => 1, :c => 2}}
%{a: %{b: 1, c: 2}}
```

How do I get back to this in an efficient way?

```
{%a: %{b: 1}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [`pop_in`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#pop_in/2). The function returns both the popped value and the rest of the value with the popped value removed. You can ignore the popped value by piping into `|> elem(1)`.

```
iex(1)> map = %{:a => %{:b => 1, :c => 2}}
%{a: %{b: 1, c: 2}}
iex(2)> pop_in(map, [:a, :c])
{2, %{a: %{b: 1}}}
iex(3)> pop_in(map, [:a, :c]) |> elem(1)
%{a: %{b: 1}}
```

or

```
iex(4)> pop_in(map[:a][:c])
{2, %{a: %{b: 1}}}
iex(5)> pop_in(map[:a][:c]) |> elem(1)
%{a: %{b: 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

with function [Map.update!](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update!/3) and [Map.delete](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#delete/2)

```
iex(1)> map = %{:a => %{:b => 1, :c => 2}} 
%{a: %{b: 1, c: 2}}
iex(2)> Map.update!(map, :a, &Map.delete(&1, :c)) 
%{a: %{b: 1}}
```

or update shortened like [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html).

```
iex(1)> map = %{:a => %{:b => 1, :c => 2}} 
%{a: %{b: 1, c: 2}}
iex(2)> %{map | a: Map.delete(map.a, :c)}  
%{a: %{b: 1}}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?